# How to find the Number of Roots of a Polynomial in a Real Range

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there a way to efficiently find the number of real roots of a polynomial $P$ in a range $[a,b]$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$? You may/may not know much about the coefficients of the polynomial, so I want methods that work based on the fact that it's a polynomial.

EDIT: I know about Sturm's theorem, but I think it would be too slow for my use case (polynomial of around degree 30), as I have to generate at most n polynomials, n being the degree of the original polynomial.

Comment: " I knew about Sturm's theorem, but I thought it was too slow (have to generate at most n polynomials, n being the degree of the original polynomial), but I didn't think to do the Descartes' thing-- however, I have a polynomial of around 30, so I don't know if it would be efficient." Please include this type of information in the question post via an [edit]

Comment: @quid Thank you for your advice. Done.

Comment: I reopened on the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).

For low degrees, one can frequently translate the variable $x \mapsto x -a$ and $x \mapsto x-b$, apply [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) to each, and also get the desired result.

Comment: @EricTowers I knew about Sturm's theorem, but I thought it was too slow (have to generate at most $n$ polynomials, $n$ being the degree of the original polynomial), but I didn't think to do the Descartes' thing-- however, I have a polynomial of around $30$, so I don't know if it would be efficient.

Comment: @DUO : [Exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) to get the bounds of an interval containing all the roots, then [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to partition that into subintervals each containing a simple real root or bounding a pair of complex conjugate roots.  (This assumes all your zeroes are simple -- not repeated.  First divide out by the [polynomial GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) of your polynomial and its derivative. (continued)

Comment: @DUO : (continues)   A repeated root of degree $n$ has degree $n-1$ in the derivative.)  Alternatively, use Sturm sequences.  Computing derivatives of polynomials is [mechanical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rules_for_basic_functions).  And then you evaluate the collection of about 30 polynomoals to determine if you have a partition element containing two eral roots (so should be subdivided) or a complex conjugate pair, so should not.
Of course, at that, skip the messing around with translation and Descartes' rule.

Comment: How can you use exponential search on a polynomial (it only works on sorted lists), or am I missing something?

Comment: Descartes' rule only gives a bound on the number of roots.

Comment: @DUO : You are searching through the sorted list of reals.  First exponential search on the left endpoint of an interval, $(u,\infty)$, guaranteed to contain zero roots.  This $u$ is an upper bound on the interval containing all roots.  Repeat on the left, $(-\infty, \ell)$, to get a lower bound, $\ell$, on the interval containing all roots.

Comment: @EricTowers And I'm guessing you find these bounds with Descartes'?

Comment: @DUO : Yes.  (padding)

Comment: @EricTowers Ok, thank you. Could you add that extra information to your post so I can accept it?

Comment: @DUO : The extra information is not responsive to the Question.  The Question explicitly asks for counting roots in a pre-specified range; it in no way asks about strategies to find that range.  Adding that information would make the Answer worse.

Comment: @EricTowers Fair enough, accepted and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no free lunch. The analytical expression of the number of real roots of a polynomial is precisely the one generated by the Sturm sequence, and no simplification has been found so far (AFAIK). So the direct method *is* Sturm's.

Other approaches (such as based on Descartes's rule) will require iterations, the number of which is unpredictable and worsens as the roots get closer to each other. (An efficient implementation can be obtained by converting the polynomial to the Bernstein basis and exploiting the "hull property" - if some coefficient differ in sign, there must be a zero. Then a dichotomic subdivision process is made efficient by De Casteljau's algorithm. [https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-sub.html;](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-sub.html;) https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e8db/366b5a403d67fd265b64b3c6e24fbf4e04cb.pdf)

In addition, I guess that for polynomials of degree 30, numerical instabilities will creep in.